# count throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: null on the file loaded from object store with inferSchema enabled

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, spark-csv

The count() on a dataframe loaded from IBM Blue mix object storage throws the following exception when inferSchema is enabled:

```
Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 43.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.9 in stage 43.0 (TID 166, yp-spark-dal09-env5-0034): java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:554)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$.castTo(CSVInferSchema.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVRelation$$anonfun$csvParser$3.apply(CSVRelation.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(CSVFileFormat.scala:127)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:91)
```

I don't get the above exception if I disable the inferSchema.
Why am I getting this exception? by default, how many rows are read by databricks if inferSchema is enabled?

Comment: What version of spark csv are you using ?

Comment: spark csv version is 1.5

Comment: and what about spark ?

Comment: spark version is 2.0

Comment: drop the spark-csv package then, upgrade spark from 2.0 to 2.1

Comment: yeah, moving to spark 2.1 worked, but I didn't understand why this worked? Would you please explain?

Comment: You always have to remember adding the info that I have asked about when asking a question. It's always easier to debug and help like this !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146362/discussion-between-eliasah-and-garipaso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually an issue with the `spark-csv` package ([null value still not correctly parsed #192](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/192)) that was dragged into `spark 2.0`. It has been corrected and pushed in `spark 2.1`.

Here is the associated PR : [[SPARK-18269][SQL] CSV datasource should read null properly when schema is lager than parsed tokens](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15767).

Since you are already using spark 2.0 you can easily upgrade to 2.1 and drop that `spark-csv` package. It's not needed anyway.

Comment: I have another question, actually the above load worked fine as a stand alone with no issues, using the same command from with in my application failed with the above exception. What could be the reason? All this is on spark 2.0.

Comment: Not likely. It's been merge in spark 2.1 and working around this can be a bit painful. ( dirty solution read as text and map(parse) then convert into a DF )